# Spring MVC remove session attribute when wizard pages left

Tags: spring, wizard

I have a wizard based on Spring MVC. To store the user input i have a RegisterCustomerForm object saved in session.
Everything works fine if i finish the wizard by clicking "finish" or "cancel". But if the user leaves the wizard by just clicking on some other link i want to remove the session attribute too. Something like a conversation scope i guess.

Is there any good way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Spring 3.1, you may take advantage of [`RedirectAttributes`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1605) which is available as of this version. [An example](http://www.tikalk.com/java/redirectattributes-new-feature-spring-mvc-31) that demonstrates how to use the feature.